# How do I create a crosstab in PySpark that gives me count of unique ids for each category?

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, pivot-table

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |
| ...10 million rows |  |

I want to make a crosstab which will give me count of unique IDs for each combination of the category.. Something like:

| Count of IDs | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 154 | 144 | 164 |
| B | 123 | 21154 | 254 |

144 IDs are present in category A and category B as well.

I have been doing group by at category first and then again pivoting by category. But the result is incorrect... Something like
df.groupby('Categoy').pivot('Category').count()

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:

```
df2 = df.withColumnRenamed("category", "category1").join(df.withColumnRenamed("category", "category2"), "customer") \
  .crosstab("category1", "category2") \
  .orderBy("cat1_cat2") 
df2.show()
```